# Weird string formatting after read() python

Tags: python, string, hex

I'm trying to read a file using Python

```
open('/Desktop/test.csv','rb').read()[1:15]
```

and I get returned something like:

```
'\xfeY\x00!\x00B\x00L\x00-\x00 \x00B'
```

Even though when I open test.csv in a text editor it is in a readable string format. Does anyone know what format this is and how to convert it back to string characters? Thanks!

Comment: You sliced of the first byte, the biggest hint was left out! :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is encoded with UTF-16.

```
>>> open('/Desktop/test.csv', 'r', encoding='UTF-16').read(7)
'Y!BL- B'
```

Or, if you're still using older Python versions,

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.open('/Desktop/test.csv', 'r', encoding='UTF-16').read(7)
u'Y!BL- B'
```

Also note that Python uses zero-based indexing, like most other languages (C, Java, C#, JavaScript, etc...)

```
>>> 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'[1:15]
'bcdefghijklmno' # Omits the 'a', which is at index 0
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing weird about that, all is well. Python is using `\x00` escape sequences to represent the non-printable characters:

```
>>> '\x00'
'\x00'
>>> len('\x00')
1
>>> '\x65'
'e'
```

Note how the hex character 65 was printed as `e`; it is a printable ASCII letter after all.

Your data is probably encoded to something different from ASCII; try decoding it with UTF-16 for example. The first 1 bytes looks like the second byte of the UTF-16 BOM to me:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.BOM_UTF16
'\xff\xfe'
```